# Bullseye Can't initialize pigpio library

Tags: pigpio, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

Help with implementing pigpio on Raspberry Pi Zero 2W, running 64 bit Bullseye...

Following the instructions for installation of the pigpio library, found in https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html :

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install pigpio - reports: pigpio is already the newest version (1.79-1+rpt1)
sudo systemctl start pigpiod - reports nothing
sudo service pigpiod - reports: pigpiod: unrecognized service
sudo pigpiod - reports: Can't lock /var/run/pigpio.pid Can't initialize pigpio library
```

Comment: `sudo systemctl start pigpiod` *"reports nothing"* -> `systemclt start` only produces output if there is a problem, so that means the service was started successfully (or was already running, `start` will not do a `restart`).   If you really want to know, **use `systemctl status pigpiod`**

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the latest version of pigpio was already installed and the daemon was already running.

If `pigs t` returns a large number (changing each time) everything is okay.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out pigpio is included with the standard PiOS Bullseye installation.

I wanted to install pigpio so that I could use PWM on Pi Zero 2W pins, which, from the resources I could find online, I understood was otherwise not available.

Under Bullseye (and the current Buster?) PWM is available on most pins through the gpiozero Python library.

Another case of read the (appropriate) docs.

Comment: You can select your own answer as the correct on if you'd like. You get no points for it, but there is some benefit to having questions with ***accepted answers*** - the benefit is to other readers who may be having the same issue.